# How to get the value of a jquery.load before appending a <select>

Tags: php, jquery

I have been reading a lot here and found very much help for my project I am actually working on (which will be a shopping portal).
Unfortunately I cannot find a solution to the following problem:

If a user (as a seller) wants to create a new product description, he has to decide in which category his new product will be filed.

So at first he selects category level1 -> jquery appends me a select after loading the option list of categories (level 2) under the selected level1 category.

No problem so far. 
But in total I have 4 levels of categories. For some categories it can happen that e.g. a level 3 category has no level 4 categories.
So after changing the value of level 3 select, it happens that i have an empty Level4 select appended.

My php script returns the option list or false if no level 4 categories are found in the database.

I am not an expert - so I have been trying it now for hours and hours to find the solution.
How to prevent that query appends me the fourth select, if it is empty?
I only have [object object] as 'value' wether I have a option list or false.

Thanks a lot for reading. Hope someone can help :-)

here is some code of my catFill.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#catLev1').change(function () {
    var $lWert = $('#catLev1').val();
    var $lang = $('#langId').val();
    var $zuordnung = null;
    $('#catLev2').remove();
    $('#catLev3').remove();
    $('#catLev4').remove();
    if($lWert !== '')
    {
      $zuordnung = $('<select id="catLev2" name="lev2" class="levelSelect"></select>').appendTo('#categories');
      $zuordnung.load('rem/remoteSearchLevelCat.php', {cat:$lWert, lang:$lang}); 
      }
    $('#catLev2').change(function () {
    $('#catLev3').remove();
    $('#catLev4').remove();
    var $lWert2 = $('#catLev2').val();
    var $lang = $('#langId').val();
    var $zuordnung2 = null;
    if($lWert2 !== '')
    {
        $zuordnung2 = $('<select id="catLev3" name="lev3" class="levelSelect"></select>').appendTo('#categories');
        $zuordnung2.load('rem/remoteSearchLevelCat.php', {cat:$lWert2, lang:$lang});
    }
    $('#catLev3').change(function () {
        $('#catLev4').remove();
        var $lWert3 = $('#catLev3').val();
        var $lang = $('#langId').val();
        var $zuordnung3 = null;
        if($lWert3 !== '')
        {
            $zuordnung3 = $('<select id="catLev4" name="lev4" class="levelSelect"></select>').appendTo('#categories');
            $zuordnung3.load('rem/remoteSearchLevelCat.php', {cat:$lWert3, lang:$lang});
        }
    });
  });
});

});
```

Ok thanks a lot!! 
I found the solution. The problem was that the .load method always returns just [object object] and there was no chance to get the length or size of the appended  because ( I guess ) it didn't exist after document.ready. So I use now  jquery .get method to handle the data I receive with this method.

Solution:

```
$.get('rem/remoteSearchLevelCat.php', { cat: $lWert3, lang: $lang })
            .done(function(data) {
            if(data !== 'false')
            {
                $zuordnung3 = $('<select id="catLev4" name="lev4" class="levelSelect"> </select>').appendTo('#categories');
                $zuordnung3.load('rem/remoteSearchLevelCat.php', {cat:$lWert3, lang:$lang});
            }
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Maybe some code would help people understand better your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague and convoluted. Let's make several assumptions based on what is given.

```
jquery appends me a select after loading the option list of categories
```

Let's assume you're doing something like this:

```
$.ajax({...   
    success: function (data) {
        (make a select box)
    }
})
```

and that `My php script returns the option list OR false`.

My question now is, why doesn't the JavaScript just check if `data` evaluates to true?

```
$.ajax({...   
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {  // if data contains anything besides false
            (make a select box)
        } else {
            (don't make a select box)
        }
    }
})
```

---

**Edit**

Err, deal with an empty dropdown box.

```
if($lWert3 !== '') {
    $zuordnung3 = $('<select id="catLev4" name="lev4" class="levelSelect"></select>').appendTo('#categories');
    $zuordnung3.load('rem/remoteSearchLevelCat.php', {cat:$lWert3, lang:$lang}, function () {
        if ($zuordnung3.find('option').length <= 0) {
            $zuordnung3.remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry for writing a convoluted question. Data evaluates always true: Wether the option string or 'fals'e if there are no level 4 categories under the before selected level 3 category

Comment: See edit... `.load` gives you a third argument that says "if the select box doesn't have any options, remove it".

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use now jquery .get and it works. I can use the (data) which i hadn't befor with the .load method

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your problem without any examples, but

> My php script returns the option list OR false if no level 4
>   categories are found in the database.

Perhaps I misunderstood, but you should check if your data, that php returns, contains the "option" string. (I assume, it returns something or false). Here is some example using jQuery's .get-method:

```
$.get('/url/to/the/php', function(leveldata) {
 if (leveldata.indexOf('option') > -1) {
   // append to the fourth select
 }
});
```

Edit:

Ok you use the jquery's load-method. Try to fetch data before you create the select element or remove the select if the content is empty.

Try this

```
...
$zuordnung3 = $('<select id="catLev4" name="lev4" class="levelSelect"></select>').appendTo('#categories');
$zuordnung3.load('rem/remoteSearchLevelCat.php', {cat:$lWert3, lang:$lang});

if ($('#catLev4 option').size == 0) {
 $('#catLev4').remove();
}
```

or this

```
    $zuordnung3.load('rem/remoteSearchLevelCat.php', {cat:$lWert3, lang:$lang},   function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpReques) {
if(responseText.length == 0) {
     $('#catLev4').remove();
}
});
```

Comment: That's not the problem - everything works fine. But I do not want to append an empty <select> if there is no option string is returned. Because thee will be no option string returned if there don't exist level 4 categories under the selected level 3 category

Comment: I have tried the solution you recommend me - but .size() (or .length) is always '0' wether it has a list of options or not

Comment: Try the latest example. Or what does $('select#catLev4 option').length output?

Comment: Ok - found the solution: I use .get and can then handle the data.  $.get('rem/remoteSearchLevelCat.php', { cat: $lWert3, lang: $lang })
                .done(function(data) {
                if(data !== 'false')
                {
                    $zuordnung3 = $('<select id="catLev4" name="lev4" class="levelSelect"></select>').appendTo('#categories');
                    $zuordnung3.load('rem/remoteSearchLevelCat.php', {cat:$lWert3, lang:$lang});
                }